# How do I iterate through the results of a sp_OAMethod 'getrows'?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I have a stored procedure that returns the resultset of a sp_OAMethod 'getrows'.

I have a need of iterating the resultset using **T-SQL**. I've searched the net for examples and I've looked into technet but can't see anything that will help.

Can you please provide code on how do it if it's possible?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why exactly are you using `sp_OA` to do anything? You know the year is 2014, right?

Comment: I haven't use MS developer/database technology in a while. But I'm using sp_OA to retrieve records from the ActiveDirectory server. If you got an alternative (link?), that'll be great. :)

Comment: Lost of much better alternatives. See [this tip](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2580/querying-active-directory-data-from-sql-server/) and [this blog post](http://www.pawlowski.cz/2011/04/querying-active-directory-sql-server-t-sql/).